# WiX Package "Comments" and "Keywords"

Tags: wix

I am having a bit of a hard time understanding the point in having the Comments and Keywords attributes with the Package element.  The WiX homepage simply says "Optional comments for browsing" and "Optional keywords for browsing."  Not overly helpful there.  Are they used in ARP, or just in the details for the MSI when it is made or what?  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These attributes map to the Summary Information Stream in Windows Installer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372046(VS.85).aspx

Basically it just provides a little additional metadata to the end user / systems administrator when they do a right click | properties on the MSI or if they are cataloging it with an automated tool.

MSDN suggests the "correct" values but really there is no such thing and this has no real important use and is not involved in ARP/Programs and Features.